# PDO update statement problems

Tags: php, pdo, sql-update

I am converting from mysqli to PDO and very much a beginner with this. Here is my update statement for my database 'users'

```
    public function pdo_update_test() {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET visible_password = ?, hashed_password = ?, ";
    $sql .="temp_hashed_password = ?, email = ?, first_name= ?, last_name = ?, ";
    $sql .="position = ?, location = ?, city = ?, country = ?, institution = ? ";
    $sql .="interests = ?, profile_comment = ? WHERE id =" . $this->id;
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $result = array($visible_password, $hashed_password, $temp_hashed_password, $email, 
                    $first_name, $last_name, $position, $location, $city, $country, $institution, 
                    $interests, $profile_comment);
    $query->execute($result);
        if (($query = $handler->prepare($sql)) === false) {
            print_r($handler->errorInfo());
        }
       if ($query->execute($result) === false) {
          print_r($query->errorInfo());
        }
      }
```

I am using ? rather than nameholders because once I have this working I am going to try to make it abstract so I can use it in all the classes in my site and I have found it easier with ? than nameholders. When I run the following it fails to work. I am sure an obvious error on my part but I can't seem to see the issue....

```
   $user = new User();
   $user->id= 256;
   $visible_password = "Bob";
   $user->pdo_update_test();
```

I have found a solution to make the whole thing dynamic. I won't presume that its going to be helpful for others (as I am the beginner) but i though I would post it anyway....

If you see problems or have criticisms please let me know

```
  public function pdo_update_test(){
    $attributes = $this->attributes();
    $attribute_pairs = array();
    foreach($attributes as $key => $value) {
      if(isset($value))
      $attribute_pairs[] = "{$key}='{$value}'";
    }
    $sql = "UPDATE ".self::$table_name." SET ";
    $sql .= join(", ", $attribute_pairs);
    $sql .= " WHERE id=". $this->id;
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array());
}
```

Comment: you have been told to turn exception mode on

Comment: many times already, as far as I remember

Comment: however, it's indeed obvious error, not on PDO part but on basic PHP syntax part.

Comment: It makes me wonder, why did you accepted the other answer if it didn't make it.

Comment: The key portion of the previous answer worked perfectly. The second part with regard to errors did not. This is also something I am working on. While I appreciate you taking the time to look at my post, your cocky attitude isn't needed. I'm not the first to point this out to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to create SET statement for the query *dynamically*. To make it contain only **actual fields you have values for**.

So, for the code given, it should produce a query

```
UPDATE users SET visible_password = ? WHERE id = ?
```

-- but **not one you wrote above** with all the fields listed

and it is not PDO related problem - it's rather just basic string manipulation, every PHP user is supposed to be able to write. If you can't, you can refer to [PDO tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for the code to adopt.

To make it work your code have to be like this

```
$user = new User();
$user->id= 256;
$data = array('visible_password' => "Bob");
$user->pdo_update_test($data);
```

where pdo_update_test will create the above SQL query out of $data array

Comment: Many thanks for this. I am going try this out and let you know.

Comment: Common Sense....Take a look at my solution if you have time. It works very well but let me know if you think its flawed. I do have 2 questions for you specifically...first is, why should $query->execute(array()); work with no variables in the array. Second is, that I followed your wiki (very good) and despite having all the errors turned on..i still get no errors...